# Creating table with Many-to-One relationship gives error in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I am trying to create a Many-to-One One-to-Many relationship in Spring Boot using JPA and Hibernate. Unfortunatly I keep getting an exception when starting the application.

This is what my Loan entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Loan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "loan_id")
    private Long loanId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="payments_id")
    private TotalPayment totalPayment;

    private String from;

    private String to;

    private double amount;

    public Loan(String from, String to, double amount) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Loan() {
    }
}
```

TotalPayment Entity looks like this :

```
@Entity
public class TotalPayment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "payments_id")
    private Long paymentsId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "totalPayment")
    private List<Loan> loans;

    private LocalDate date;

    public TotalPayment(LocalDate date) {
        this.loans = new ArrayList<>();
        this.date = date;
    }

    public TotalPayment() {
    }
}
```

This is the console output when I execute the application:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table loan (loan_id bigint not null auto_increment, amount double precision not null, from varchar(255), to varchar(255), payments_id bigint, primary key (loan_id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.arno.verrekenappbackend.VerrekenAppBackendApplication.main(VerrekenAppBackendApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=784) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from varchar(255), to varchar(255), payments_id bigint, primary key (loan_id)...' at line 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:153) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:274) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:363) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:501) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from varchar(255), to varchar(255), payments_id bigint, primary key (loan_id)...' at line 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException.of(MariaDbSqlException.java:34) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.exceptionWithQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:192) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:260) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:357) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from varchar(255), to varchar(255), payments_id bigint, primary key (loan_id)...' at line 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1681) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1543) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1506) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:254) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

2021-03-27 15:04:01.073  WARN 20984 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table loan add constraint FK5tudqyp3n6yn5svagvbko379v foreign key (payments_id) references total_payment (payments_id)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table loan add constraint FK5tudqyp3n6yn5svagvbko379v foreign key (payments_id) references total_payment (payments_id)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.arno.verrekenappbackend.VerrekenAppBackendApplication.main(VerrekenAppBackendApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=784) Table 'verrekenapp.loan' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:153) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:274) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:363) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:501) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException: Table 'verrekenapp.loan' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException.of(MariaDbSqlException.java:34) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.exceptionWithQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:192) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:260) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:357) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'verrekenapp.loan' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1681) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1543) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1506) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:254) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.2.jar:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: try adding this in properties file.
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from` and `to` are special keywords in MariaDB, you need to change the name of those columns. Or you can try:

```
@Column(name = "`from`")
private String from;

@Column(name = "`to`")
private String to;
```